# How to extract some value from diff fields of an object in one command

Tags: json, jq, json-query

there is json data like this

```
➜  ~ cat foo.json | jq
{
  "data": {
    "foo": [
      {
        "table": "aaa"
      },
      {
        "table": "bbb"
      }
    ],
    "bar": [
      {
        "table": "ccc"
      },
      {
        "table": "ddd"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Could get table of foo or bar separately,

```
➜  ~ cat foo.json | jq '.data.foo[].table'
"aaa"
"bbb"
➜  ~ cat foo.json | jq '.data.bar[].table'
"ccc"
"ddd"
```

how could get all table values in one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the comma operator.

```
$ jq '.data["foo", "bar"][].table' foo.json
```

or

```
$ jq '.data | .foo, .bar | .[].table' foo.json
```

Or assuming you want to grab any property of the `data` object.

```
$ jq '.data[][].table' foo.json
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care where the "table" values occur, and if you want to exclude `null` and `false` values:

```
.. | .table? // empty
```

If you want to include `null` and `false` values:

```
.. | objects | has("table") | .table
```